# Terminal goes slow after install Mavericks OS

Tags: terminal, xcode, macos

After I've update my OS to Mavericks.

Terminal goes really slow, I've found out that the problem must be from Xcode.

While I remove Xcode from my computer terminal works fine, and after I installed Xcode,  it goes slow again.(It takes like 2 second for `ls` command)

Please help.

PS. my computer is MacBook Pro with Retina.

Comment: Are you using ZSH and the vi-mode plugin? https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2189

Comment: yeah, I've solve the problem after reset my `.zshrc`. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem to and I was looking for the way to solve it.

Checking at the issue that Adam Albrecht commented, it looks like the problem was being caused by the zsh vi-mode plugin in combination with the apple provided git.

Installing git from homebrew solve the problem without having to deactivate the vi-mode plugin

Comment: I've just solved it after reset my `.zshrc`. thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer! The update apparently mixed up my path so the system git was before brew git. Now everything works again. Thanks!